# I get duplicated data when drilling down multiple series to single series

Tags: highcharts

I've just managed to do [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7dt1786/) which works, and I can't see the difference between that and my code whose json is below. Both points are listed and I don't see the difference between what I've written and the code in the fiddle.

```
{data: [{
drilldown: "164",
name: "pigs",
y: <value>}...
```

and

```
{data: [{
color: '#ffffff',
drilldown: "164",
name: "pigs_food",
y: <value>}
```

So there are two series, both of which I want to drill down to the same series. I'm using an async request, but I can't figure out what is going wrong. I could post more data on request. I can't see what's going on at all.

---

Solved.
Turns out that the options I was using to add the drilldowns asynchronously and efficiently were adding the series twice so I added in a check.

Comment: Could you paste all your json ? It seems like you have a problem between `drilldown` attribute and `id` attribute.

Comment: In a jsfiddle would be perfect :)